# Extracting the title and abstract from a webpage

Tags: php, string, url, meta

I am trying to extract the title and abstract from arXiv pages, for example http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0102, my code currently looks like

```
function get_title($url){
  $str = file_get_contents($url);
  if(strlen($str)>0){
    $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str)); // supports line breaks inside <title>
    preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title); // ignore case
    return $title[1];
  }
}

echo get_title("http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0102");
```

When I run this code, this error comes up

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0102): failed to
>   open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\Index.php

This problem doesn't happen when I try different urls for example http://www.washingtontimes.com/.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Also, is it possible to extract the abstract from this webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the response of the website that don't allow empty user agents:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>

 <p>Sadly, your client does not supply a proper User-Agent,
 and is consequently excluded.</p>
 <p>We have an inordinate number of problems with automated scripts
 which do not supply a User-Agent, and violate the automated access
 guidelines posted at arxiv.org
 -- hence we now exclude them all.</p>
 <p>(In rare cases, we have found that accesses through proxy servers
 strip the User-Agent information. If this is the case, you need to contact
 the administrator of your proxy server to get it fixed.)</p>


<p>If you believe this determination to be in error, see
<b>http://arxiv.org/denied.html</b> for additional information.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you use for example the user agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" in your request, it will work:

```
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$str = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: Thank you this is great. Just one last question: Do you know how extract the abstract from this page http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0102? I would be very grateful if you could help me

Comment: @user3741635: please make a new question of it and show what you have done so far to extract the abstract.